# GCM _ java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to pick up GCM by following the [developer.android.com/google/gcm](https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/client.html) but have end up with the following error:

> 11-05 08:12:53.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1873): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
>   11-05 08:12:53.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1873): Process: com.example.gcmtest00, PID: 1873
>   11-05 08:12:53.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1873): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
>   11-05 08:12:53.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
>   11-05 08:12:53.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
>   11-05 08:12:53.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
>   11-05 08:12:53.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
>   11-05 08:12:53.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
>   11-05 08:12:53.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
>   11-05 08:12:53.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
>   11-05 08:12:53.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
>   11-05 08:12:53.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1873): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to start service Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER pkg=com.google.android.gms (has extras) } without permission com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE
>   11-05 08:12:53.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon(ContextImpl.java:1503)
>   11-05 08:12:53.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.app.ContextImpl.startService(ContextImpl.java:1480)
>   11-05 08:12:53.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startService(ContextWrapper.java:494)
>   11-05 08:12:53.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.c(Unknown Source)
>   11-05 08:12:53.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging.register(Unknown Source)
>   11-05 08:12:53.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at com.example.gcmtest00.MainActivity$getRegId.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:53)
>   11-05 08:12:53.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at com.example.gcmtest00.MainActivity$getRegId.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
>   11-05 08:12:53.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
>   11-05 08:12:53.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>   11-05 08:12:53.147: E/AndroidRuntime(1873):     ... 4 more

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.gcmtest00"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="16"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<permission android:name="com.example.gcmtest00.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcmtest00.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.gcmtest00.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver
        android:name="gcm.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <category android:name="com.example.gcmtest00" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <service android:name=".GcmMessageHandler" />

</application>
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.gcmtest00;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
    public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
    private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    Button btnRegId;
    TextView etRegId;
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm=null;
    String regid;
    String SENDER_ID = "186386566618";  //project number
    Context context;
    AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
    SharedPreferences prefs;
    static final String TAG = "GCMDemo";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        context = getApplicationContext();

        btnRegId = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGetRegId);
        etRegId = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.etRegId);

        if (checkPlayServices()) {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            regid = getRegistrationId(context);
            if (regid.isEmpty()) {
                registerInBackground();
            }
        }else {
            Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
        }
    }

    private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }

        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }

    private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {

        return getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
                            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    private static int getAppVersion(Context context) {
        try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                            .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {  
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkPlayServices();
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
                finish();
            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void registerInBackground() {
            new AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>(){

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
                String msg = "";
                try {
                    if (gcm == null) {
                        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                    msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;

                    sendRegistrationIdToBackend();

                    storeRegistrationId(context, regid);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();

                }
                return msg;
            }
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
                etRegId.append(msg + "\n");
            }
        }.execute();
    }
    private void sendRegistrationIdToBackend() {

    }

    private void storeRegistrationId(Context context, String regId) {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        int appVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, regId);
        editor.putInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, appVersion);
        editor.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add:

`<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />` within the `intent-filter` tag of the `receiver`